# Clipping shapefile using intersected shapefiles in R

Tags: r, polygon, crop, shapefile, clip

I'm trying to clip (not crop according to extent) U.S. state and county shapefiles to match the boundaries of this DEM (digital elevation model) clipped raster.

[image: "DEM"]

My cropped (according to extent) state shapefile looks like this:
[image]

How do I clip the state shapefile to match the complex outline of the DEM?  I have tried intersecting the two, which works, but that does not distinguish between the state and watershed boundaries, making the map very difficult to read (especially with counties!).  [image]

```
huc6_cty_intersect <- raster::intersect(huc6s, counties)
```

I need to be able to overlay the states and counties separately, so I can change their border width, color, etc so the maps are readable.

I have tried rasterizing the state and county shapefiles, and then masking by the dem, but that seems to take a very, very long time (overnight was not enough time).

```
counties_rast <- rasterize(counties, dem)
r4 <- raster::mask(counties_rast, huc6_cty_intersect)
```

I am trying to get to the following image, but with all state boundaries outside the watersheds chopped off.  Any help in how to do this would be wonderful.  Thank you.  [image]

NOTE: the white elevations within the watershed boundaries are masked out on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you are looking for `raster::crop`

```
library(raster)
b <- as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(b) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"    
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))

pb <- crop(p, b)
```

Comment: You are *not* providing a reproducible example. You should not show *your* data, but some example data like I do. Anyhow, it still looks like my answer solves you problem. Did you try it? `raster::crop(states, huc6s) `

Comment: It works, but it leaves "residuals" of the huc6s data within the cropped state data.  Thank you.